# Expectation with respect to empirical distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space and $X$ a random variable with distribution $P$. The expectation of some measurable function $g$ with respect to $P$ is

$$
\mathbb{E}_P[g(X)] = \int_\Omega g(X(\omega))\, dP(\omega).
$$

The empirical distribution $Q$ of i.i.d. samples $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ from $P$ is defined as

$$
Q(B) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_B(x_i) \quad B \in \mathcal{A} \,.
$$

I know that
$$
\mathbb{E}_Q[g(X)] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)
$$
but it is not obvoius how to derive this starting with
$$
\mathbb{E}_Q[g(X)] = \int_\Omega g(X(\omega))\, d\left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_\omega(x_i) \right]
$$

Answer (score 6):

I think for any realization of random variable : $ X_{1},...,X_{n}$, the empirical distribution $F_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{\{X_{i}\le x\}}$ is just a discrete distribution function concentrated on these n value and attached weight $\frac{1}{n}$ to each of them. Thus, the integral $\int g(x)dF_{n}(x)$ is same as expected value of $g(x)$ with respect to a discrete distribution: $$\int g(x)dF_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(X_{i})$$ I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the simplest case where the empirical distribution is simply $\delta_{x_1}$, i.e. the number of samples $n$ is just 1. (I like the delta notation more than the indicator function.) Then, the expectation is simply evaluation:

$$ \int_\Omega g(x) d\delta_{x_1}(x) = g(x_1)\,. $$
(This is the key point to understand).

If $n=2$, the empirical distribution is $Q = \frac12 (\delta_{x_1} + \delta_{x_2})$. The expectation is

\begin{align*}
    \int_\Omega g(x) dQ(x) &= \frac12 \left( \int_\Omega g(x) d\delta_{x_1}(x) +  \int_\Omega g(x) d\delta_{x_2}(x) \right)
    \\ 
    &= \frac12 (g(x_1) + g(x_2))\,. 
\end{align*}

Similarly, for general $n$, we have $Q(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}(x)$ and

$$ \int_\Omega g(x) dQ(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i),. $$