# Proof that Expectation of a Function with respect to the Empirical Distribution is the Average of the Function Evaluated at the Observed Points

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can someone please provide the proof or point to any reference with detailed steps?

## Question,

Why is the expectation of a function with respect to the empirical distribution, the average of the function evaluated at the observed points as shown below?

Defining the empirical distribution function as,
$$
  \hat{F}_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n I_{[x_i,\infty)}(t) \, ,
$$

Why does it follow that?
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\,d\hat{F}_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i) \, .
$$

[Related Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76359/integrate-with-ecdf-quickly-in-r)

I was unable to find this proved on the website or elsewhere. If very well known result, am happy to delete the question, once someone gives me a reference with detailed steps.

Comment: You only need to prove this result for a single sample. Do you understand this case, and in particular what $d F$ means?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, So in the case of a single sample, $n=1$. No, I do not understand this case? I understand somewhat what $dF$ means but not sure, how that relates to $d\hat{F}_n(t)$. So please clarify with no assumptions on background if possible.

Comment: Again, you are turning around the definition of $d\hat F_n$. In the present case, $$d\hat F_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{x_k}$$ where each $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure at $x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1267634/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of $dF_n(t)$ provided above by @Did,

First we note a useful result and the required follows as shown below,
$$
\int_{0}^{K}dF_{n}\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{K}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{X_{i}}\left(t\right)dt=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\in\left[0,K\right]\right\} }}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}=F_{n}\left(K\right)
$$
$$
\left[\because dF_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{X_{i}};\text{ Here, }\delta_{x}(A)=1_{A}(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\not\in A;\\
1, & x\in A.
\end{cases}\text{ is the Dirac measure}\right]
$$
More generally,
$$
\int_{0}^{K}g\left(t\right)dF_{n}\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{K}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g\left(t\right)\delta_{X_{i}}\left(t\right)dt=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g\left(X_{i}\right)\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}g\left(t\right)dF_{n}\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g\left(t\right)\delta_{X_{i}}\left(t\right)dt=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g\left(X_{i}\right)\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq\infty\right\} }}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g\left(X_{i}\right)
$$