# Proof of Expectation involving the Empirical Distribution Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

## Question,

Please suggest how to prove the following:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\left(K-t\right)^{+}\right]dF_{n}\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{K}F_{n}\left(t\right)dt
$$

Here, $K>0$ ;  $\left[\left(K-t\right)^{+}\right]=\text max\left[\left(K-t\right),0\right]$ and $F_{n}\left(t\right)$ is the empirical distribution function of a positive valued random variable.

Please let me know if you need any further clarifications or if this follows from standard results regarding the empirical distribution. Please point to references if available.

## Steps Tried

## 1)

To use integration by parts, I suppose the below holds trivially (Does it really???) and this approach works.

$$
\int dF_{n}\left(t\right)=F_{n}\left(t\right)
$$

But the real problem, I had was because this link says that:

[Derivative of the empirical distribution function is either zero or undefined.](http://eml.berkeley.edu/~powell/e241a_sp06/ndnotes.pdf)

Perhaps, this brings up the validity of using $dF_{n}\left(t\right)$ in the first place.

## 2)

Alternately, using the result: 
[Expectation of a function with respect to the empirical distribution is the average of the function evaluated at the observed points.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340290/proof-that-integral-of-a-function-with-respect-to-the-empirical-distribution-is)

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\left(K-t\right)^{+}\right]dF_{n}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(K-X_{i}\right)^{+}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(K-X_{i}\right)\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}K\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}
$$
$$
=KF_{n}\left(K\right)-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq K\right\} }}
$$

## 3)

Alternately, using the Riemann sum to solve the definite integral on the RHS,

$$
\int_{0}^{K}F_{n}\left(t\right)dt=\underset{m\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\sum_{j=1}^{m}F_{n}\left(t_{j}\right)\Delta t\quad;\Delta t=\frac{K-0}{m};t_{j}=0+\frac{jK}{m}
$$
$$
=\underset{m\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\sum_{j=1}^{m}F_{n}\left(\frac{jK}{m}\right)\frac{K}{m}
$$
$$
=\underset{m\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n}\sum\boldsymbol{1_{\left\{ X_{i}\leq\frac{jK}{m}\right\} }}\frac{K}{m}
$$

I was also trying to use the above approaches. But perhaps, these are just unneccesary complications. Happy to delete this question, if it is just noise.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

By Danny Chan:

I rephrase your question: Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a distribution function with $F(0)=0$. Let $K>0$. Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}(K-t)^{+}dF(t)=\int_{0}^{K}F(t)dt.$

Proof:
Let $A=\{(x,y)\mid0<y\leq x\leq K\}$ be the triangular region with vertices
$(0,0)$, $(K,0)$, and $(K,K)$. Clearly $A$ is a Borel subset of
$\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$
induced by $F$. That is, $\mu((-\infty,x])=F(x)$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Let $m$ be the usual Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
Note that the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
coincides with $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. Consider the product
measure space $(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2}),m\times\mu)$.
By Tonelli-Fubini Theorem, we have 
$$
\int1_{A}d(m\times\mu)=\int\!\int1_{A}(x,y)\,dm(x)d\mu(y)=\int\!\int1_{A}(x,y)\,d\mu(y)dm(x).
$$

Note that the second integral is equal to $\int_{(0,K]}(K-y)\,d\mu(y)=\int_{[0,\infty)}(K-y)^{+}dF(y)$
(observe that $\mu(\{0\})=0)$, while the third integral is equal
to $\int_{0}^{K}\mu((0,x])\,dm(x)=\int_{0}^{K}F(x)\,dx$.

Hence we have: $\int_{0}^{\infty}(K-t)^{+}\,dF(t)=\int_{0}^{K}F(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: $(K-t)^+$ is $0$ for all $t\geq K$. The right integral must contain the density of a random variable, right? Or it must be just $dF_n(t)$ inside the integral.

Comment: "I did try integration by parts and using the definition of empirical distribution etc and was getting stuck" If you did try this, the details of your try should be expanded upon in your question before we can answer you usefully.

Comment: @stud_iisc Sorry but what?

Comment: @Did Basically i was trying to say that there must be a typo in the RHS.

Comment: @Did, Please note, I have added the steps tried and some reasons for my confusion. Deleted my earlier comment just to reduce noise. Thanks

Comment: "Perhaps, this brings up the validity of using $dF_n(t)$ in the first place." What this brings up is that you do not really know what $dF_n(x)$ means. In this context, $dF_n$ is the nonnegative measure, uniquely defined by the identity $$\int_0^xdF_n(t)=F_n(x)$$ for every $x\geqslant0$. The identity you are after follows.

Comment: @Did, thanks for this clarification. I suppose, we need to bring measure theory concepts into this. Do you see a way without using measure theory for problems of this kind?

Comment: Without restriction on $F_n$, this seems impossible, from a mere logical point of view.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I am sort of beginning to see why measure theory becomes important. Though, I am not sure how we can restrict $F_{n}$ since it is well defined. But to have a notion of a derivative (wrong word perhaps) or $dF_{n}$, using your comment on the related question. I can see how this result comes about. What got me confused was this link: [Derivative of the empirical distribution function is either zero or undefined.](http://eml.berkeley.edu/~powell/e241a_sp06/ndnotes.pdf)

Comment: Why are you still confused by this? **As I already explained to you**, $$d\hat F_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{X_k}$$ is a linear combination of Dirac measures hence indeed, $\hat F_n$ is constant on intervals and making jumps of height $\frac1n$ from one interval to the next.

Comment: @Did, Thanks I see it.  I "was" confused because of that link. In fact, I used your suggestion above to form an answer on the other question, which I added a few minutes back.

Comment: @Danny, I wanted to suggest that you add your edit as an answer, but I am seeing that the question is not open for new answers. I have accepted this edit for now; but your change is more appropriate as an answer I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Did comments:

Put $u = (K-t)^+$ and $dv = dF_n$

and then do $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$, limits would get transformed from 0 to $\infty$ to 0 to K.